# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when using miniaudio

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the miniaudio library into my program but I am runnining into an issue, when I use the basic example of playback I get numerous errors in the terminal that follow the pattern of:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_AudioComponentFindNext", referenced from:
      ma_context_init__coreaudio(ma_context*, ma_context_config const*, ma_backend_callbacks*) in main.cpp.o
```

there are 18 of these errors each pointing to a different functions in the miniaudio file, the image attached is the full error message.

I have made sure to add miniaudio to my cmake.

main.cpp

I have made sure to add miniaudio to my cmake.

```cpp
#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "miniaudio.h"


void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount)
{
    ma_decoder* pDecoder = (ma_decoder*)pDevice->pUserData;
    if (pDecoder == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    ma_decoder_read_pcm_frames(pDecoder, pOutput, frameCount, NULL);

    (void)pInput;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ma_result result;
    ma_decoder decoder;
    ma_device_config deviceConfig;
    ma_device device;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("No input file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    result = ma_decoder_init_file(argv[1], NULL, &decoder);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS) {
        return -2;
    }

    deviceConfig = ma_device_config_init(ma_device_type_playback);
    deviceConfig.playback.format   = decoder.outputFormat;
    deviceConfig.playback.channels = decoder.outputChannels;
    deviceConfig.sampleRate        = decoder.outputSampleRate;
    deviceConfig.dataCallback      = data_callback;
    deviceConfig.pUserData         = &decoder;

    if (ma_device_init(NULL, &deviceConfig, &device) != MA_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to open playback device.\n");
        ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);
        return -3;
    }

    if (ma_device_start(&device) != MA_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to start playback device.\n");
        ma_device_uninit(&device);
        ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);
        return -4;
    }

    printf("Press Enter to quit...");
    getchar();

    ma_device_uninit(&device);
    ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);

    return 0;
}
```

cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(C__NetworkPractice)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(C__NetworkPractice main.cpp miniaudio.h)


target_link_libraries(C__NetworkPractice PUBLIC)
```

Comment: Library != header (most of the time). The header usually only describes the library and another file implements it. Somewhere there is a .a  or .lib file that holds the definitions of all the stuff in the header. That's what the linker's looking for. The header stuff was all handled correctly by the compiler or you wouldn't have gotten to the linker.

Comment: `add_executable(C__NetworkPractice main.cpp miniaudio.h)` doesn't look right to me.  `main.cpp` already includes `miniaudio.h`  Does removing it from there make it work?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(C__NetworkPractice PUBLIC)` Normally you have some library name or alias / CMake target name after the PUBLIC.

Comment: @user4581301 In this case the library is really a single header file.  It just requires adding `#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION #include "miniaudio.h"` to one source file.

Comment: @NathanOliver Finding that out myself. Comes as a shock.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, removing miniaudio.h does not fix it I receive the same number of errors

Comment: Did you define `MA_NO_RUNTIME_LINKING` or `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` ? Those require you to link to the CoreAudio frameworks explicitly. Your code compiles just fine on my M1 Mac so something not shown in your question is causing this.

Comment: @Botje I did define both of those but the IDE states "Macro 'MA_NO_RUNTIME_LINKING' is never used" and still gives the same errors, I'm using CLion if that makes a difference

Comment: You are not supposed to define either macro! I was asking if something was setting them by accident, because that requires you to link against the framework yourself.